# Why is the bounding rectangle of the selection range wider than the actual text selection?

Tags: javascript, css, layout, bounding-box

I need to get the bounding rectangle of the text selection. I am using this code:

```
    if (window.getSelection && window.getSelection().rangeCount) {
      var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneRange()
      if (range.getBoundingClientRect && range.getBoundingClientRect()!=null)
        return range.getBoundingClientRect()
    }
```

But it often returns a rectangle that is much wider than the text selection, even though every element of the selected text doesn't extend that wide.

For example, when I select the text of the fist two paragraphs of https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluon the rectangle includes the picture to the right.

It seems that the problem occurs every time when the paragraph boundary is inside of the text selection, and this makes the rectangle to extend to the paragraph width.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The image being included in the multi-paragraph selection may be a problem for what you want to accomplish or the way you want to interpret the document structure--yet isn't "wrong" from the point of view of the HTML/CSS layout model or the browser's layout engine.

Simplifying the document structure:

```
<div id="nw-content-text">
    <div style="float: right">
        <img src="gluons.png">
    </div>
    <p>From Wikipedia...</p>
    <p>Gluons are what hold quarks together...</p>
    ...
</div>
```

In Chrome e.g., inspect the page. Then in the Elements view select either of the `<p>` tags. The rendered view will show highlighted background extending across the image area:

[image: show para image overlap]

That's because the image floating to the right is indeed consuming part of the paragraph's maximum possible bounding box. If you want to consider just paragraph text, that feels wrong, but it's how the CSS layout model works. Depending on your font sizes and such, you may be able to select the third para as it flows underneath the image, and it indeed flows to the same far right edge.

Given the `float: right` of the image's container, the browser "thinks" the image and its container `<div>`s "lives" to the right of the first para, but before the second. That is its logical "attachment point" or "anchor point." Select the first para, and the browser knows the image isn't included. Select the second, and likewise. Select the combination, though, and the image is correctly included because the anchor point lives between the two paragraphs. Ask for the bounding box of either para alone and the browser responds with a tight box. But ask for tbe bounds of the selection that spans those paras, and it must include the anchor point and contained image that anchor point represents. The much larger bounding box including the image is the right answer.

Okay, so much for the layout theory explaining **why** this happens as it does. Now **how** to get it to do what you want it to do, and exclude the contained image from the selection bounding box?

Given that CSS and the browser doesn't interpret the selection the way you want, you won't be able to use `getBoundingClientRect()` on the selection directly. However, you can navigate from the selection to the nodes included, and filter out any tags that you don't want. In this case, you seem to only want `<p>` tags, which are easy enough to filter for. Compute the bounding box of each para in your selection, then return a box that is the union of them.

Beware that working with ranges is a bit tricky, especially as browsers historically had different models for how to manage them. A cross-browser library like [rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy) might help, though simply navigating from a range to the underlying nodes probably doesn't require that much extra framework. There are quite a few articles on Stack Overflow about "getting from JavaScript selection to underlying nodes," with many code samples. They're not all simple...but just filtering for paras is a fairly simple case. Or if you don't want to dive into all the range issues, you can use something like [Selection.containsNode()](https://w3c.github.io/selection-api/#widl-Selection-containsNode-boolean-Node-node-boolean-allowPartialContainment) to less elegantly but still quickly iterate through possible nodes and see if they're in the selection.

Also beware: Your example document makes things simple by just needing filtering for paras, and by having just one floating item to exclude. But the variability across all HTML / CSS documents is *enormous*. That variability can make solutions fragile. E.g. if sometimes you need to filter for more than just `<p>` elements, or need to filter into the middle of text nodes not affiliated with a tightly-wrapped tag, things quickly get more dicey. The variations and the different edge cases will complexify your reinterpretation of what a selection's bounding box should enclose (and should ignore).